# page number move to the left of the page when items per page is clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using paging in my mat-table. The paging is showing the number of pages, but the page numbers move to the left of the page instead of displaying inside the page drop down:

Below is the screen shot

[image]

when I click on the Items Per Page; only 5 displays inside the box. Rest of the page number move to the left as you can see under test1. Below is my HTML code:

```
<div>
 <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,25,100]" [pageSize]="5"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

below is my .ts code:

```
export class PersonDataComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;

    ngOnInit() {
    this.LoadProjectData();
    this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.personlist);
  }


   LoadProjectData() {

    this.service.getProjectData().subscribe((tempdate) => {
      this.personlist = tempdate;
      console.log(this.personlist);
      if (this.personlist.length > 0) {
        this.dataavailable = true;
        this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.personlist);
        this.listData.sort = this.sort;
        this.listData.paginator= this.paginator;

      } else {
        this.dataavailable = false;
      }

     }), err => {
        console.log(err);
      };
  }
```

I am not sure why the page numbers are not displaying towards the left of the page instead of inside the items per page drop down.
any help will be greatly appreciated. Above code is mostly related to paging. I omitted other code.

Comment: Recreate the problem press F12 then inspect the element. You will see the style on right side. Experiment with it to find what works then put that style into that Page's Css. Use same name as in f12.

Answer (score 1):

My angular Material theme was not enabled and that was causing the page numbers to move to left. I enabled the material theme by putting this in my style.scss file.

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```